# All possible combinations across arrays in nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, algorithm

Lets say I have three arrays:

```
var arr1 = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow',];
var arr2 =  ['car', 'bus'];
var arr3 =  ['china'];
```

How to get the following combinations:
1. Order matters,
2. Each result(can be a array) should contain 0..1 element of each arr
3. Element of arr1,arr2,arr3 can appear 0..1 times ：

```
red,car,china
red,china,car
car,red,china
car,china,red
china,car,red,
china,red,car

red,bus,china
red,china,bus
bus,red,china
bus,china,red
china,bus,red,
china,red,bus

orange,car,china
orange,china,bus
bus,orange,china
bus,china,orange
china,bus,orange,
china,orange,bus

orange,bus,china
orange,china,bus
bus,orange,china
bus,china,orange
china,bus,orange,

yellow,car,china
yellow,china,car
car,yellow,china
car,china,yellow
china,car,yellow,
china,yellow,car


yellow,bus,china
yellow,china,bus
bus,yellow,china
bus,china,yellow
china,bus,yellow,
china,yellow,bus

red,car
car,red

red,bus
bus,red

orange,car
car,orange,

orange,bus
bus,orange,

yellow,car
car,yellow,

yellow,bus
bus,yellow,

red,china
china,red,

orange,china
china,orange,

yellow,china
china,yellow,

car,china
china,car,

bus,china
china,bus,

red, 
orange, 
yellow, 
car, 
bus, 
china,
```

What I could not figure out is  how to control the appear times in the element of each arr, my code is as follows:

```
function get_titles_appearances(titles_columns) {
    titles_columns = titles_columns || [];
    var n = titles_columns.length;
    if (n === 0) { return [] }
    if (n === 1) { return titles_columns[0] }

    var save = function () {
        var m = groups.length, c = [];
        while (m--) { c[m] = groups[m] }
        rtn.push(c);
    }
    var i = 0, len = 0, counter = [], groups = [], rtn = [];

    for (; i < n; i++) {
        counter[i] = 0;
        groups[i] = titles_columns[i][0];
    }
    save();

    while (true) {
        i = n - 1, len = titles_columns[i].length;
        if (++counter[i] >= len) {
            while (counter[i] >= len) {
                if (i === 0) { return rtn }
                groups[i] = titles_columns[i][0];
                counter[i--] = 0;
                counter[i]++;
                len = titles_columns[i].length;
            }
        }
        groups[i] = titles_columns[i][counter[i]];
        save();
    }
    }

                _.forEach(get_titles_appearances(titles_columns_config_default), function (value) {
                    // titles_appearances.push(  _.join(value, '')+"':'"+_.join(value, ','))
                    titles_appearances = titles_appearances+"{"+ _.join(value, '')+":"+_.join(value, ',')+"},"
                })
        titles_columns_config_default refer to [arr1,arr2,arr3]
```

Comment: Please don't post programming assignments. Post questions about code you wrote.

Comment: I guess you should first check permutations vs combinations

Comment: You missed a few results, among them all the 1 and 0 element results.

Comment: thx all guys  ,i made a few edits ,if it is still not proper, i can delete it

Comment: No, that's much better. Indent should be fixed, then it will be all-right!

Comment: @Redu for  permutation ,i did find these fabulous lib,                      
https://github.com/jgallen23/combinations                     
https://github.com/dankogai/js-combinatorics                        
i have tried to combine  all arr1,arr2,arr3 into one ,but i got a out of memory error because of my real arr is a little large
        Combinatorics.permutationCombination(total)

Comment: @Henry   i edit my question again